# How to change dummy variable from 1 to value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df, df.head(3) looks like...

```
  number|Player
  - - - - - - - 
   10   | Messi
   7    | Ronaldo
   14   | Henry
```

Want to get it to look like this...

```
Number|Messi|Ronaldo|Henry
--------------------------
10    |10   |0      |0
7     |0    |7      |0
14    |0    |0      |14
```

I've tried using map, apply and get_dummies() but the later has 1 instead of the values.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you essentially trying to one-hot encode? I see you've tagged as machine learning, why is why I'm asking.

Comment: yeah trying to one-hot encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = df[["number"]].join(pd.get_dummies(df["player"]).mul(df["number"], axis=0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `pivot_table`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "number": [10, 7, 14],
    "player": ["Messi", "Ronaldo", "Henry"]
})
df["value"] = df.number
df["number"] = df.number.astype(str)
df.pivot_table(values="value", columns="player", index="number").fillna(0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.get_dummies`:

```
df = df.set_index('number')
df_out = (df['Player'].str.get_dummies()*df.index).reset_index()
df_out
```

Output:

```
   number  Henry  Messi  Ronaldo
0      10      0      7        0
1       7      0      0       14
2      14     10      0        0
```